# how to handle execution timeout in flink

Tags: apache-flink

```
        Connected to JobManager at Actor[akka.tcp://flink@localhost:6123/user/jobmanager#-1119198862] with leader session id 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000.
org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: The program execution failed: Couldn't retrieve the JobExecutionResult from the JobManager.
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.ClusterClient.run(ClusterClient.java:478)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.StandaloneClusterClient.submitJob(StandaloneClusterClient.java:105)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.ClusterClient.run(ClusterClient.java:442)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.ClusterClient.run(ClusterClient.java:429)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.ContextEnvironment.execute(ContextEnvironment.java:62)
    at FileSetWordCount.main(FileSetWordCount.java:178)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:528)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.invokeInteractiveModeForExecution(PackagedProgram.java:419)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.ClusterClient.run(ClusterClient.java:381)
    at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend.executeProgram(CliFrontend.java:838)
    at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend.run(CliFrontend.java:259)
    at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend.parseParameters(CliFrontend.java:1086)
    at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend$2.call(CliFrontend.java:1133)
    at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend$2.call(CliFrontend.java:1130)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.HadoopSecurityContext$1.run(HadoopSecurityContext.java:43)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1556)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.HadoopSecurityContext.runSecured(HadoopSecurityContext.java:40)
    at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend.main(CliFrontend.java:1130)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobExecutionException: Couldn't retrieve the JobExecutionResult from the JobManager.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobClient.awaitJobResult(JobClient.java:309)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobClient.submitJobAndWait(JobClient.java:396)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.ClusterClient.run(ClusterClient.java:467)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobClientActorSubmissionTimeoutException: Job submission to the JobManager timed out. You may increase 'akka.client.timeout' in case the JobManager needs more time to configure and confirm the job submission.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobSubmissionClientActor.handleCustomMessage(JobSubmissionClientActor.java:119)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobClientActor.handleMessage(JobClientActor.java:251)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.akka.FlinkUntypedActor.handleLeaderSessionID(FlinkUntypedActor.java:89)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.akka.FlinkUntypedActor.onReceive(FlinkUntypedActor.java:68)
    at akka.actor.UntypedActor$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(UntypedActor.scala:167)
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:467)
    at akka.actor.UntypedActor.aroundReceive(UntypedActor.scala:97)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:516)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:487)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:238)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:220)
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:397)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
No JobSubmissionResult returned, please make sure you called ExecutionEnvironment.execute()
```

This is an exception threw by Flink. How to handle the client timeout exception? This Flink application is going to run in the local envirionment. The application is used for about 1TB files processing.

Comment: Please provide more information. What kind of program are you running? What's the cluster environment? ... Without this information, there's little chance that somebody can help you. Moreover, please use appropriate formatting for your question.

Comment: Please update and format your question. Did you notice the last line of the exception and check if you called `ExecutionEnvironment.execute()`?

Comment: Thanks anyway, I have figure it out. It is necessary to modify the 'flink-conf.yaml' file with  adding a new line "akka.client.timeout: xx s"(e.g. "akka.client.timeout: 600 s").

Comment: You can also answer the question yourself and accept the answer.

Answer (score 3):

I have figure it out. It is necessary to modify the 'flink-conf.yaml' file with adding a new line "akka.client.timeout: xx s"(e.g. "akka.client.timeout: 600 s").