# Flink not reading the File from S3 when running in EC2

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, apache-flink

I have multiple data in S3 inside a bucket. I was trying to run my Flink program in EC2 instance. I do have IAM role in EC2 and able to read the data from S3. But when I run the program I get the following error:

`Submitting job with JobID: 445b8130e310bcb791afff2301c40b16. Waiting for job completion.
No JobSubmissionResult returned, please make sure you called ExecutionEnvironment.execute()`

My pogram does has `env.execute()` at the end of the program. I am pretty much sure that it is not able to fetch/read the files from S3. My code looks like the following:

`DataSet<Tuple2<String, String>> datalines=env.readCsvFile("s3://CopyOfData/Days/")
                    .fieldDelimiter("|")
                    .types(String.class, String.class);`

Please help me how to over come this. My flink-conf.yaml has also HADOOP_CONF_DIR set.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by checking the JobManager and TaskManager logs for clues. You can also review this list of [common issues for Flink on AWS](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/ops/deployment/aws.html#common-issues).

It could also be that you need to increase the akka.client.timeout. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47283186/how-to-handle-execution-timeout-in-flink), but in short, try adding something like `akka.client.timeout: 600 s` to flink-conf.yaml.

Comment: Sir, after adding `akka.client.timeout: 600 s` to flink-conf.yaml I still get the same error.

Comment: I've updated my answer to suggest you check the logs for clues.

Comment: Are you trying to read one CSV file, or a directory full of them? I believe readCsvFile only works with single files.

Comment: Thank you. In log file I got the following error:
`ava HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x00000000c0000000, 1073741824, 0) failed; error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 1073741824 bytes for committing reserved memory.
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/ec2-user/flink-1.4.2/bin/hs_err_pid23975.log`

can you please tell me how to fix the lower and upper limit of memory?

Comment: To your question I would like to tell you that inside data folder i have two files named data1.csv and data2.csv. According to Flink documentation I believe if i mention the folder it will look for all the files inside it.

Comment: Anyone can help me in this? I am still getting same error even after increasing the memory to m4 large.